GitHub Action - Sync two repos on push of a main repo
I am trying to make a GitHub action that syncs a repo in my organization to the repo we are making the actual changes on I have tried to look for videos and such but can not quite find a solution to the goal I have in mind.
I have tried a GitHub action that used a python script to do the bulk of the syncing but I’m having a hard time also setting up the token for organization use
